# Accessing computed properties of app root from child component in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to access a computed property of my app root in one of my child components, but I can't seem to find any way to. My app is set up like so:

App.vue

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, onUnmounted, computed } from 'vue'
  import Board from './components/Board.vue'
  ...
  const guessNotInDictionary = computed(() => { ... } )
  ...
</script>
```

Board.vue

```
<script setup>
  import Row from './Row.vue'
  ...
</script>
```

Row.vue

```
<script setup>
  import Tile from './Tile.vue'
  ...
</script>
```

Tile.vue

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
  const app = getCurrentInstance()
  ...
</script>
```

The computed property `guessNotInDictionary` is properly defined, because when I display its value in App.vue's template, I get correct values that update properly. But when I access `app.root.guessNotInDictionary` from Tile.vue, I get `undefined`. `app.root` does return the root instance, as I have logged it in the console, but there is not a `computed` property on that object, like there is for `data` or `props`.

Suggestions?

EDIT:
I have tried passing props down the chain of children, but I seem to be losing the reactive state. When the computed property changes values, none of the children's values are updated.

EDIT 2:
Nvm. It was a small typo that was preventing the prop from being passed properly. It is all working now. Thanks!

Comment: Props down, events up. When you want to pass a prop to a child, you just specify it on the child `<child :someProp="someValue" />`. This will create a live binding between the value in the parent and the one in the child. If you find this pattern (called prop-drilling) too cumbersome, consider using external state management solutions e.g: either `reactive([})` instances or a `pinia`/`vuex` store.

Comment: When I chain props like that, I seem to be losing the reactive state. When the computed value changes, the prop values in children aren't changing.

Comment: Provide an actual *runnable* [mcve] (on codesandbox.io or similar) and I'll be able to tell you why it's not working. I guarantee it has nothing to do with the fact that in the parent component the value comes from `props`, `data` or `computed`. It doesn't matter, they all work the same when passed to children. It must be something else, probably related to how the child consumes it.